# Proving $A_{n}$ is not invertible for n>2 when the entries are sequential integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_{n}$ be the nxn matrix whose entries are the integers 1, 2, 3,..., n-1, n, written in order from left to right, top to bottom. For example,
$$A_{5}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5\\6&7&8&9&10\\11&12&13&14&15\\16&17&18&19&20\\21&22&23&24&25 \end{bmatrix}$$
Prove that A is not invertible for any positive integer n>2.

I have noticed that for any matrix $A_{n}$, the 2 x 2 corners will seem to always be invertible. Any other n x n partition on the corners of the matrix do not seem to be invertible.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: Compare the sum Row 1 + Row 3 and Row 2

Comment: @QuangHoang Why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @QuangHoang Then to apply this to any $A_n$, would I need to write a proof using induction? I've done very little induction so I'm not too sure if it would apply here.

Comment: No, you don't need to use induction. It applies for all $n>2$ (You need $n>2$ because that argument involves $3$ rows.)

Comment: Then how would I go about proving that it applies to all $n\gt 2$ without explicitly showing it, i.e. writing all appropriate $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: Just write down the general term of $A_{1k}+A_{3k}$ and $A_{2k}$ for any given $n$ and you're done, no need for induction.